# Wildcard mapping folders in IIS rewrite module

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewrite-module

I am hoping you can all help me. I'm currently creating a blank ASP.Net MVC site to act as a 301 redirect application.

I've currently configured the IIS rewrite module to use separate file like below.

```
<rewrite>
<rules configSource="rewriteRules.config" />
<rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMaps.config" />
</rewrite>
```

This is working fine and I have some static rules working, however I need to redirect a URL and any other files under that to a specific URL and I'm not sure of the best and most efficient way of accomplishing this.

For example I need to redirect:

/folder and /folder/file-name to the URL http://www.another-domain.com/this-page

I have about 50 folders (and all child pages within this folder) that I need to redirect to 50 new URLs.

So is it possible to set one rule up and use the rewriteMaps.config to manage the wildcard mapping.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Kevin